# Remove duplicate but add score in google sheets query and group with just 1 of 2 teamnames

Tags: google-sheets

I have a small issue where I use a query function in Google sheets to display a score of drivers that are mostly also in a team. I use a separate Data sheet for it to enter the scores and all details.

The query function in my case should select certain columns to display in a different tab. It does that perfectly, but one of the names in there changed teams. This means I had to add the person a second time in the data table with a different team name so the team scores don't get mixed up.

Now I would like the query function to display this person only once in combination with his latest team name (I put that above the old team name in the data table) and add the scores of both to make a driver points score and a legit team score.

Long story short, this is what the function looks like and it should not display this extra rule without messing up the other points in there.

```
=QUERY('Championship Data'!B4:O952; "select B,C,D,O where O is not null order by O desc, B asc")
```

[image: Championship Data]

In the picture below you can see that the name Manuel is in there twice, but I would like to have the name in there with the team Radicals Online Trak Racer and 20 points in 1 row.
[image: Driver Standings]
If someone would please help to check the functions in action and see if they can fix the minor issue? Thanks!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: player0 I just did (y)

Comment: What about using [unique](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) along with [filter](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) ? Also, could you please share a sample sheet so that we can tests our solutions in there without having to reproduce all your sheet? Many thanks ! :D

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf, here is the link to the duplicate:

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lxb1MYidHUhgvq1mCcQP6cMir35wLodkVv5rsEYf9OM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for providing the link. Are you open to have an Apps Script solution or would you exclusively like a Google Sheet formula solution?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I would like to have a Google Sheets formula solution but if you can fix it temporarily it would be great also through a script solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your request of solving this using preferably Google Sheet formulas rather than Apps Script, I have developed a possible solution/workaround in the fewer amount of steps I could.

To achieve what you aimed here (only display unique members according to their names), I was not able to use query but rather a series of formulas that led me to a similar solution as if you would have used query.

1. Filter the names to only display a list of the unique members (no duplicate names) so that we don't have twice the same person *(in the image showing the solution, this formula is implemented in `B2`)*:

`=unique(filter('Championship Data'!B4:B952;NOT(ISBLANK('Championship Data'!O4:O952))))`

2. Get the row index of the names obtained (i.e the row numbers they are in) to then get the rest of the column information we are interested in *(implemented in `A2` and then dragged all the way down until we cover all the names)*:

`=MATCH(B2;'Championship Data'!$B$4:$B$952;0)+3`

3. In the columns `C`, `D` and `E` we will use this row index along with the column we want to get the information from in the sheet `Championship Data` to get the right values from the other sheet *(and then just drag all the way down until we cover all the names)*:

Car number : `=INDEX('Championship Data'!$A$1:$O$952;A2;3)`

Team : `=INDEX('Championship Data'!$A$1:$O$952;A2;4)`

Total : `=INDEX('Championship Data'!$A$1:$O$952;A2;15)`

4. Finally, using the table we just created, we apply two `sort` functions for the columns of names and total to order them accordingly:

`=SORT(SORT(B2:E34;1;TRUE);4;FALSE)`

### Note

To place the right total value to Manuel, I have had to add these points in the first table created as otherwise it would be practically impossible to change his score (unless we change it manually or with a script). To do so I changed the cell `E3` to this: `=INDEX('Championship Data'!$A$1:$O$952;A3;15)+20`

[image]

Comment: Hey Mateo, I just implemented this work around and after some trial and error it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot for your help because I need this before Saturday ;)